# How can I keep some form fields intact when using JSON to dynamically populate some fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, populate

I'm using jquery Populate to dynamically populate a field with the previous Firstname and Surname fields. All fields are in the same form. 
The problem is when I populate the field using Populate javascript:
$(formname).populate(newfieldvalue)

It clears all the other form fields. Is there a way I can keep the other fields intact. It's a large form so I would prefer not to pass all the values back through.

Comment: Which populate plugin are you using ?

Comment: [jQuery Populate](http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html). Ian's answer fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set resetForm to be false (default is true) in the options hash which is passed to populate.

```
$(formname).populate(newfieldvalue, {resetForm: false});
```

For more information on populate options, check out the bottom of [this page](http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html).

Comment: That's it, thanks. I didn't realise it defaulted to true. Thank you.